# Error calling GRASS from R Studio (Mac)

Tags: r, grass-gis

I am trying to call GRASS GIS from R Studio.

```
GRASS_path <- ("Applications/GRASS-8.3.app/Contents/Resources")
gisDbase <- ("Users/PS/grassdata")
location <- ("TH_N32") 
mapset <- "PERMANENT"

G<-initGRASS(gisBase = GRASS_path, gisDbase =  gisDbase, location = location, mapset = mapset, override=TRUE)
```

That throws the error

```
sh: g.gisenv: command not found
sh: g.gisenv: command not found
sh: g.version: command not found
Error in system(paste("g.version", get("addEXE", envir = .GRASS_CACHE),  : 
  error in running command
```

This occurs in R Studio under macOS 13.4. Switching to GRASS 7.8 does not resolve the issue. However, this issue does not occur in R (g.gisenv and g.version are present in the bin folder).
Calling GRASS from R Studio also works flawlessly on my old Mac.

There was an earlier discussion here on this issue on Windows, bit that did not help me further.

Comment: Update: It works fine when I do library(rgrass7) prior to library(rgrass). While this solves the issue, it leaves me wondering why and what will happen after Oct. 2023 when rgrass7 is archived.

Comment: Which version of `rgrass` do you use? However, the best place to ask might be here: https://github.com/rsbivand/rgrass (there is an issue tracker).

Comment: version 0.3.8. It works for now, but I will visit the link.